# get_results not returning anything

Tags: wpdb, user-meta

What is the basic way to use $wpdb and get_results?

This is my code:

```
global $wpdb;
$q="SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'nickname' AND user_id = 771";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($q);
echo $result;
```

The query string is good because I can run it in phpmyadmin and it works fine. I am not getting anything back when run through page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$wpdb->get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) returns an array on success, so you can't simply `echo $result;`.

Instead, you can use `foreach` to loop through the results and display whatever the data that you want to display:

```php
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $q );
foreach ( $results as $row ) {
    echo $row->meta_value . '<br />';
}
```

But I can see that you're trying to select just *one row*, so you'd want to use [`$wpdb->get_row()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/) and not `$wpdb->get_results()`:

```php
$row = $wpdb->get_row( $q );
if ( $row ) {
    echo $row->meta_value;
}
```

But then again — because `wp_usermeta` is the default table for WordPress users' meta, if you just want to retrieve the meta value, then there's a function you can (and should better) use — [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/):

```php
echo get_user_meta( 771, 'nickname', true );
```

Comment: Thank you! get_user_meta worked perfectly. I might try the other options as well just for my own edification. Thanks again

Comment: Awesome. :) And would you please kindly mark the answer as correct? Doing so would help others know the question has an accepted solution.